# Depth of Field - Visible Lines on Distance Change

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine, depth-of-field

As the distance of my Depth of Field effect changes (EEVEE), visible lines are drawn across the objects on which the effect is happening. These lines are the 'thresholds', I presume, between different levels of blurriness.

Focus on the 'Komsomol' as the camera starts moving. Lines are only visible in motion, not paused.

https://youtu.be/Vqxnez8iq_0

Is there a way I can stop this happening and smooth out this effect for Eevee?

Comment: There is a "Max Size" setting in the render settings for depth of field when using Eevee, maybe this can help ?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaENX.png

Comment: I turned it down to about 20 to increase render time. Default is like 100, but that takes a long time. Is this the cause?

Comment: Does it fix the problem ?